# How to unique number (7 digits only) for each line in the file

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have function in which I am looping large text file (which has 200K records - very big bank file).
I need write to the file with unique number for each line in the file. For example i need to maintain unique customer number.

- Customer number (Total 17 length) = Policy number (10 digits) + Unique number (7 digits)

So here I know Policy number but for Unique number, I am planning to generate using timestamp in a for loop. So my question will that be unique? or is their any better approach to maintain 7 digit unique number in a for loop (considering performance as well, since its big file).

This is my code :

```
Var CustomerNumber =  row.Policynumber + DateTime.Now.ToString("MMddFFF"); // Miliseconds
```

I tried for last 7 digit with MMDD and Milliseconds combination - will this be unique?

Comment: `200K` isn't very big. A timestamp won't generate unique values either, even if you use ticks (100ns). Why not just use the row number? Or a combination of timestamp and row number? Or perhaps a global counter? If you only have a single thread, this could be a static field. Even with multiple threads you could use `Interlocked.Increment` to increase the counter safely

Comment: Even starting with `1,000,000` and going for 200k iterations, you're still well below the [maximum value of `Int32`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.maxvalue?view=net-5.0#remarks) which is 2,147,483,647. Is there a reason you cannot simply increment an `int` with each iteration of the loop? Does the sequence of unique numbers need to be unpredictable?

Comment: my code is -single thread

Comment: Have you looked at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Random ?

Comment: I should maintain 7 digits all the time for unique number , If i use increment it will start from 1 digit. Please Note - Length of unique number should be always 7 digits only - it should not be less or more

Comment: @Manas You can use an incrementing value and then pad it with zeros. Look at `PadLeft`. i.e. `i.ToString().PadLeft(7, '0');`

Comment: Just because an increment starts at 1, doesn't mean you can't represent it as a 7 character string. String.Format("{0:0000000}", num) will produce 7 characters with leading zeros.

Comment: So, are there duplicate instances of the policy number in the file? Does the "unique number" have to be unique across all rows of the file only? Does the "unique number" have to be unique across duplicate policy numbers? Does the "unique number" have to be unique across multiple executions on the same file?

Comment: Hi Daniel, good question, yes their will be duplicate instance of Policy number in a file. Yes If we have "unique number" it should be unique across all the file.  so that If the policy number duplicate then PolicyNo + unique number combination will be unique to that row.

Comment: If you need a unique number across the whole file then it sounds like you need a unique record ID. As you read the file, count the number of records you have read then append the ID as @DanielMann suggests. Using a timestamp is not guaranteed to be unique if you can read the data fast enough.

Comment: Just use the line number, as suggested. You also don't need to start in 1, you can start in `1_000_000` as the first line number.

Comment: @lcryder Random and unique are two different things. Random doesn't guarantee uniquiness.

Comment: @lcryder in fact, a truly random sequence will have a *lot* of duplicate, even repeating numbers and sequences. 5 consecutive 1s have the exact same chance of happening like *any* other 5 number combination

Comment: Thank you all for the valid input , I will go with increment 1 by 1 and then do the Leftpad.